# How do I get the cancelled alert to return to the same former option after alert "cancel"?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, alert, html-select

How do I get the option box to return to the same former selected place after "cancel" selected in the alert?

Right now the code works, right now it goes to "disabled" option called "Common Languages" that has no functionality. That is not how it should work.

**What I want is to return to the former selected option after choosing "cancel" in alert.**

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', ':not(form)[data-confirm]', function(e){
    if(!confirm($(this).data('confirm'))){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$(document).on('submit', 'form[data-confirm]', function(e){
    if(!confirm($(this).data('confirm'))){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$(document).on('input', 'select', function(e){
    var msg = $(this).children('option:selected').data('confirm');
    if(msg != undefined && !confirm(msg)){
        $(this)[0].selectedIndex = 0;
    }
});
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<select name="LangF" id="opt">
<option value="" disabled>Common Languages:</option>
<option value="zh-CN">Chinese (Simplified)</option>
<option selected value="en">English</option>
<option value="fr">French</option>
<option value="de">German</option>
<option value="ru">Russian</option>
<option value="es">Spanish</option>
<option value="" disabled>&#8212;</option>
<option value="auto" data-confirm=" The ´´Automatic Language Detection´´ does not detect laguadges in frames / sandbox. Are you sure you want to select this option? ">Auto Detect</option>
<option value="" disabled>&#8212;</option>
<option value="" disabled>Other Languages:</option>
<option value="af">Afrikaans</option>
<option value="sq">Albanian</option>
<option value="ar">Arabic</option>
<option value="hy">Armenian</option>
<option value="az">Azerbaijani</option>
</select>
```

Right now it works, but the problem is that it goes to the 1 value of the option that is called "Common Languages:" value that is "disabled". I think there must be a way to make it go to another value like for example the automatic "selected" value called "English" from the option if not the former selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution (total code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', ':not(form)[data-confirm]', function(e){
    if(!confirm($(this).data('confirm'))){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$(document).on('submit', 'form[data-confirm]', function(e){
    if(!confirm($(this).data('confirm'))){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
var arr = [];
$(document).on('input', 'select', function(e){
    arr.push($(this)[0].selectedIndex)
    var msg = $(this).children('option:selected').data('confirm');
    if(msg != undefined && !confirm(msg)){
        $(this)[0].selectedIndex = arr[arr.length-2];
    }
});
</script>
```

nothing changed here:

```
<select name="LangF" id="opt">
<option value="" disabled>Common Languages:</option>
<option value="zh-CN">Chinese (Simplified)</option>
<option selected value="en">English</option>
<option value="fr">French</option>
<option value="de">German</option>
<option value="ru">Russian</option>
<option value="es">Spanish</option>
<option value="" disabled>&#8212;</option>
<option value="auto" data-confirm=" The ´´Automatic Language Detection´´ does not detect laguadges in frames / sandbox. Are you sure you want to select this option? ">Auto Detect</option>
<option value="" disabled>&#8212;</option>
<option value="" disabled>Other Languages:</option>
<option value="af">Afrikaans</option>
<option value="sq">Albanian</option>
<option value="ar">Arabic</option>
<option value="hy">Armenian</option>
<option value="az">Azerbaijani</option>
</select>
```

It really works.

Comment: Okay either I am confused or I do not know how to do it. I can not manage to make your code work together with the code I use. So can you please show me an example. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: okay, if you choose english language, this selected language will be pushed into the array that we have declared globally, and then you will select auto-detect, there will be box that pops up, when click on cancel, the option will stay on the same old language which is english. @SeekLoad

Comment: Agreed that is exactly how I want it to work, sadly it does not work on my page. I do not know what I did wrong with your code?

Comment: okay no problem, my answer is part of your code, hope you did not delete the rest of it. @SeekLoad

Comment: That is why I said "can you please show me an example" on how to put the code. Because the ``<script type="text/javascript">
var arr = [];
$(document).on('input', 'select', function(e){
    arr.push($(this)[0].selectedIndex);
    var msg = $(this).children('option:selected').data('confirm');
    if(msg != undefined && !confirm(msg)){
        $(this)[0].selectedIndex = arr[arr.length-2];
    }
});
</script>`` does nothing and I also tried implanting with and in my code in different ways. Still nothing.

Comment: of course it won't, my bad, I've edit it, check it out. @SeekLoad

Comment: No I did  not delete the rest of the code. I saw that it looks much like my code so I tried to implement it. But I can not figure out how, because were ever I implement it, it simply does nothing, except instead it makes my code 100% useless. But maybe I am doing something wrong. So plz give me an example of were and how to implement it in my code...

Comment: OK wait i will look, I was writing when you edited. Wait

Comment: sure no problem, take your time. @SeekLoad

Comment: Now it sort of works, but only sort off. If I chose "another language" first and then "Auto" and "cancel", it works. But if I have just loaded the page and chose "Auto" directly and "cancel", it does not work. It will still goes to the "disabled" value "Common Languages"

Comment: That's right, because whenever you refresh the page the array that you have declared will empty itself, there won't be saved data.@SeekLoad

Comment: children('option:selected') seem to have no effect to go to "selected" option when the page is newly loaded without me trying other languages first.

Comment: Correct, so then I may need some function that will call the "selected" value when clicked "cancel" if not anything else was chosen before.

Comment: Theoretically it should be "OK / Auto" or "CANCEL / if value / else selected value"

Comment: Or if that is not possible, then "CANCEL / go to selected value" regardless of what value was chosen before the change. Because even if that is not preferred, it is a loot better then to have a "disabled" value chosen.

Comment: yep, that's right, I am not sure about this function structure, but I will look out for it. @SeekLoad

Comment: yea that is my problem too. I am not sure how to get that. I mean we all know that you can chose OK and go to a value that you chose. So why not use Cancel to do the same, but to a different value?

Comment: And I have nothing against if it says YES and NO instead of OK and Cancel either. That is just a simple bagatelle that has no importance in this case.

Comment: At least you went 50% of solving the problem. So somewhat you are on the right track. Maybe I need a onload something to make your code see it as if I chose "English" so it would react the same way as if I did chose and not just loaded the page.

Comment: yeah, there will be a lot of `if` statements somehow. @SeekLoad

Comment: I made a more simple code too:
``<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $('#opt').change(function() {
  var selected = $(this).val();

   if (selected == 'auto') {
   if (!confirm('The ´´Automatic Detection´´ does not detect languages in frames. \n Are you sure you want to select this option?')) {
    $(this).val($.data(this, 'current')); // added parenthesis (edit)
    return false;
    } 
   }
  $.data(this, 'current', $(this).val());
 });
});
</script>`` It works the exact same way as yours but it selects the "disabled" value called "Other Languages:" instead

Comment: You can test that code too, if your curious. Maybe there is a solution there instead, if the first code is too hard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149419/discussion-between-seekload-and-zainab-hammami).

Comment: It is a bit long, but UPDATES are now added.

Answer (score 0):

After the form loads, cache the state in an object.  You can write a function to update this cached object so upon a success you can easily update the cache for future use cases when a cancel or error occurs.  You can make another function to cycle through the cached object and set the properties (and values).  This is the only way I know of without using a page reload or reloading the data via ajax (websocket, etc).

Comment: Right now it works, but the problem is that it goes to the 1 value of the option that is the "Common Languages:" value that is "disabled". I think there must be a way to make it go to another value like for example the automatic "selected" value called "English" from the option if not the former selected value.

Comment: I think I understand now.  The user selects and option and the reset of the select element defaults to the first item instead of what was selected when the form was submitted and and user canceled the submit.  You can still cache what was selected.  Add an event listen, upon change of the select statement, update the cached element.  Then upon a cancel, let the form reset and then update which option was selected.  If you just want the first one that is not disabled use something like this:  $($('#opt option"]').attr('disabled', 'false')[0]).prop('selected', 'selected');

Comment: It is a bit long, but UPDATES are now added.